# How to select the data in a given way?

Tags: data, filtering

Consider the data

```
data = {{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2},{x3,y3,z3},{x4,y4,z4},{x5,y5,z5},{x6,y6,z6},...}
```

with N rows.

It can be divided into N/6 sets of 6 rows. I want to select a subdata obtained from the sets satisfying some specific requirement for 3rd rows of the sets, say `data[[3+6*i]][[2]]>10`.

Example:

```
data = {{1,2,3},{1,9,6},{1,12,6},{1,5,6},{1,6,3},{1,5,5},{3,5,6},{1,10,6},{1,8,6},{1,4,6},{1,0,4},{1,3,6}}
```

The data contains 2 sets of 6 rows. In the first set we have data[[3]][[2]]>10, in the second set we have data[[9]][[2]]<10, and therefore after imposing the criterion `data[[3 +6*i]][[2]]>10` we obtain

```
subdata = {{1,2,3},{1,9,6},{1,12,6},{1,5,6},{1,6,3},{1,5,5}}
```

Comment: What is the question? You seem to have obtained what you want...

Comment: Is this what you want? `Select[Partition[data, 6], #[[3, 2]] > 10 &]`

Comment: @march : that's almost what I wanted. I just need to remove partition afterwards. Could you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: `Select[Partition[data, 6], #[[3, 2]] > 10 &]~Flatten~1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
partitions = Partition[data, 6];
Pick[partitions, UnitStep[partitions[[All, 3, 2]] - 10], 1]
```

> {{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 9, 6}, {1, 12, 6}, {1, 5, 6}, {1, 6, 3}, {1, 5, 5}}}

You can also use undocumented 6-argument form of `Partition`:

```
Partition[data, 6, 6, 1, {}, If[{##}[[3, 2]] > 10, {##}, Nothing] &]
```

> {{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 9, 6}, {1, 12, 6}, {1, 5, 6}, {1, 6, 3}, {1, 5, 5}}}